# Why is lowering and raising index not affecting the value of a tensor?

Tags: tensors, tensor-rank

I have two questions to ask about:

1. For example I have a tensor $T(r,s)$ by which it means that $T$
   operates on $r$ vectors and $s$ dual vectors. Take for example
   $T(3,0)$, so in this notation it only operates on three vectors.
   Then I heard that by raising or lowering indices one can manipulate
   the number of vectors and dual vectors a tensor can act on without
   affecting the value. In the above example, it means, e.g. $T(3,0) =
   T(2,1) = T(1,2) = T(0,3)$ (note that those four notations are usually written with differing notation for $T$ because they are now different object if a lowering or raising index has been done, but I don't bother to make them have different notation just for my convenience). Are those equalities true?
2. I just want to check if my understanding about the definition of
   tensor is correct. Tensor is any multilinear operators/functions
   which return a scalar. An example of a tensor is the inner product
   in real vector space. However, inner product in a complex vector
   space is not a tensor because it's conjugate linear (i.e. not
   linear) in one of the arguments. Is it right?

EDIT: I reworded my questions to make it clear that I have two questions now. The first one has been unofficially answered as it is written as a comment.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean "does not affect the value of the tensor".

Comment: What is the "value of a tensor" that you say is not affected?

Comment: Like you say, a conjugate bilinear form is not $\Bbb C$-linear. It is, however, $\Bbb R$-linear over the underlying *real* vector space.

Comment: One uses a metric tensor to raise or low indexes. If the metric is trivial, i.e. $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ your claims right. Otherwise would be wrong.

Comment: take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map#Properties to see how is this in a presence of a metric... specifically at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map#/media/File:FourfacesofBilinaearmaps.PNG

Comment: @Travis, $T(v,w)$ returns a scalar right? That's what I mean by value.

Comment: @janmarqz, which claim of mine are you referring to? I will simply quote a sentence from my textbook "If $T$ is of type (1,1) with components $T_i^j$ , for instance, then we may turn it into a tensor $T$ of type (2,0) with components $T_{ij}$".
Moreover, please describe trivial in this case.

Comment: Sure, but the scalar $T(v, w)$ is the value one gets when evaluating $T$ on a pair of vectors $v, w$. If we raise an index of $T$, we get a tensor $T^{\sharp}$ of type (1, 1), but it doesn't make sense to talk about the "value" $T^{\sharp}(v, w)$---after all $T^{\sharp}$ takes as arguments a covector and a vector, but $v$ and $w$ are both vectors.

Comment: What is true is that one can lower an index of $v$ to get a covector $v^{\flat}$, and then $T^{\sharp}(v^{\flat}, w) = T(v, w)$, so in this sense "the values are the same", but for the above reason I'd avoid that terminology.

Comment: Anyway, one certainly shouldn't say that $T^{\sharp} = T$, as $T, T^{\sharp}$ are different objects. Regarded as functions, they don't even have the same domain.

Comment: Why does it not make sense to talk about the value of $T^{\sharp}(\tilde{v}, w)$? Is it not scalar? The tilde indicates covector.

Comment: So, it's numerically true that $T^{\sharp}(v^{\flat}, w) = T(v, w)$. My ultimate question is, how do I prove this equation?
Or else... is it that this equation is that from which the lowering and raising indexes are defined?

Comment: That's the definition indeed.

Comment: I have redone some parts of my question so that what I want to ask about are clear. Can somebody leave the [on hold] status?